# Safely modify opcodes in x86 binary

Tags: x86, gdb, reverse-engineering, patch, disassembly

Given a binary analyzed with gdb for example, I want to "patch" the binary by modifying some bytes in it (so that some custom code is executed). For example, the following :

```
leave
ret
push   $0x108f6680
jmp    0x49c0028
...
```

Could be modified so that it looks like that :

```
sub %esi, 0x0
jne <short range>
leave
ret
...
```

Unfortunately, as far as I know, this is not a safe modification (even if in the first block of code it looks like what has been discarded was some junk code never executed) because in x86, the same opcodes can be reused in different instructions (there is some instruction overlap). Nonetheless, is there a safe method to modify those bytes (maybe somewhere else in the binary?) ? I want the binary to still execute normally, except that there is my added code basically.

N.B : This is done for educational purposes on my own binaries, nothing illegal here.

Comment: Did you mean `sub $0, %esi` since you're using AT&T syntax?  Rather than subtracting ESI *from* the contents of memory at absolute address 0?  If so, I guess just to set FLAGS, in which case `test %esi,%esi` / `jne` is even shorter than sub or `cmp $0, %esi`.  (If you're not used to AT&T syntax, you can tell GDB to use Intel syntax; `set disassembly-flavor intel`

Comment: One easy way to see if anything else jumps to those bytes is to replace them with `0xcc` bytes, the debug-breakpoint opcode.  But an obfuscated binary might have data packed into padding between functions, so you could also set a watchpoint there in a debugger.  It's not very likely that the `leave` and `ret` and the following bytes are all part of some longer instruction if execution starts from a different point.  They are only 1 byte each, but that seems super weird.  (Compiler-generated code never does stuff like that; static disassembly always just works.)

Answer (score 0):

> Unfortunately, as far as I know, this is not a safe modification ... because in x86, the same opcodes can be reused in different instructions (there is some instruction overlap).

No compiler will do that. This can only happen if the binary is intentionally obfuscated, and jumps into the middle of instruction.

> This is done for educational purposes on my own binaries

If you didn't put such obfuscation into your binary (i.e. if it's simply a compiler-generated binary), then you don't need to worry about "instruction reuse".

Comment: Non-obfuscated binaries normally have NOPs or `0xcc` (`int3`) padding between functions, not stuff like `push  imm32` and `jmp rel32`.  When they say "my own binaries", I think they mean they're not going to distribute modified binaries, (or use online for an online game), just playing around with existing binaries they have on their own system.  Not necessarily that they built themselves from source code, although that's certainly an easier place to start with binary modification because you can figure out where each part of the binary comes from.